# Stored Procedure with Pivot Does Not Return Result Structure but Zero Value

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

[MyActualresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhpK3.png)I am trying to get count of data which have particular status on different dates. Something like tracking shipment and getting today's report.

I have used Pivot with stored procedure. I get result as column and rows but return value `null` on executing the Sp.

Can any one please suggests how can I rectify the issue?

I tried to put the query in some variable and then execute but its not done correctly.

```
    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCountOfShipmentWithStatus]

    @DateToStart Date,
    @DateToEnd Date,
    @LabName nvarchar(30)

    AS
    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        WITH TrackShipment AS
    (
      SELECT exData.ID, CAST(ExpectedDeliveryDt AS DATE) AS Deliverydate,A.AccountCode,L.Name, DATENAME(dw, ExpectedDeliveryDt) AS DayOfWeek,exData.MileStoneTypeId AS TrackingStatus,exData.AccountNo 
      FROM [Tracking].[TrackingExternalData] exData
      Left Join [systemManagement].[SystemMetaData] sysmetadat on exdata.MileStoneTypeId=sysmetadat.systemMetaDataId
      Left Join  [Data_Replication_EZSHIP].[dbo].[AccountNumber] AS A on exData.AccountNo=A.AccountCode
      Left JOIN [Data_Replication_EZSHIP].[dbo].[Location] AS L ON A.LocationId = L.Id 
      WHERE L.Name=@LabName
      AND sysmetadat.systemMetaDataId IN ('E770CE7C-E0E6-40C6-AC51-5D2129F2DEB7','D6A011C8-C39C-45B5-9127-52D20C68E1C3','C7657AE1-9354-E911-BB4A-005056B00B08','559ECEC2-969A-4F8C-9A95-21C613D82F3A')
      AND exData.ExpectedDeliveryDt <= @DateToStart AND exData.ExpectedDeliveryDt >= @DateToEnd
      )

    SELECT  Deliverydate, DayOfWeek, 
            -- List of Pivoted Columns
            [E770CE7C-E0E6-40C6-AC51-5D2129F2DEB7],[D6A011C8-C39C-45B5-9127-52D20C68E1C3], [C7657AE1-9354-E911-BB4A-005056B00B08], [559ECEC2-969A-4F8C-9A95-21C613D82F3A]
    FROM TrackShipment

    PIVOT 
    (
       COUNT(Id)
       -- List of Pivoted columns
       FOR TrackingStatus IN([E770CE7C-E0E6-40C6-AC51-5D2129F2DEB7],[D6A011C8-C39C-45B5-9127-52D20C68E1C3], [C7657AE1-9354-E911-BB4A-005056B00B08], [559ECEC2-969A-4F8C-9A95-21C613D82F3A])
    ) as pvt
    ORDER BY Deliverydate DESC


    END
    GO
```

I expect return value same as result of pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this condition is incorrect:

```
exData.ExpectedDeliveryDt <= @DateToStart AND 
exData.ExpectedDeliveryDt >= @DateToEnd
```

I don't know what you intend, because you haven't provided sample data, desired results, or an explanation of the logic you want.

But I am guessing that the comparison are backwards:

```
exData.ExpectedDeliveryDt >= @DateToStart AND 
exData.ExpectedDeliveryDt <= @DateToEnd
```

Comment: Hi agree that condition needs to be altered i have done that .

Comment: I have added a pic of [actual result ] what i need is return value same as result.